# How to add product sku beside of product name in header in product edit in admin in magento 2

Tags: product, magento2.3, header, product-edit

I want to add the SKU beside the product name in "product edit page" at the admin-side in magneto 2? i have changed in Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit.php here

```
public function getHeader()
{
    if ($this->getProduct()->getId()) {
        $header = $this->escapeHtml($this->getProduct()->getName().'#sku'.$this->getProduct()->getSku());
    } else {
        $header = __('New Product');
    }
    return $header;
}
```

but it is not working in magneto 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page title has been set in the controller file for the admin product edit page. You can update the product name using a plugin of the controller function.

Create the following files in your module to update the product name.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit">
        <plugin name="add_sku_after_product_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product;

class Edit
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($product->getName() . ' (' . $product->getSku() . ')');
        return $result;
    }
}
```